# How to maintain reference/pointer/link to vector element after change to vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, data-structures, reference

I have a `std::vector` of a custom class (using `int` in sample for simplicity). I would like to keep a reference/pointer/link/other to a member of the vector. However, the vector frequently has elements removed and added.

To illustrate my point, in the sample below I take either a reference or a pointer to the second element of the vector. I use the reference/pointer to increase the value of the chosen element. I then erase the first element, and use the ref/pointer to increment again.

Reference example:

```
std::vector<int> intVect = {1,1,1};
int& refI = intVect.at(1);
refI++;
intVect.erase(intVect.begin());
refI++;
```

Smart-Pointer example:

```
std::vector<int> intVect2 = {1,1,1};
std::shared_ptr<int> ptrI = std::make_shared<int>(intVect2.at(1)) ;
*ptrI = *ptrI +1;
intVect2.erase(intVect2.begin());
*ptrI = *ptrI +1;
```

What I would like to happen is to end up with the referenced element to have a value of 3, the final vector being composed of `{3,1}`. However, in the reference example, the final vector is `{2,2}`, and in the pointer example the final vector is `{1,1}`.

Understanding that the pointer is essentially a memory address, I can understand why this method might not be possible, but if it somehow is, let me know.

**The more important question** is then, what alternate approach or structure could be used that would allow for some form of ref/pointer/link/other to that element (be it a value or an object) that is viable after adding members to, or removing members from, the vector(or other structure) that contains it?

**For extra credit:**

The objects I am actually working with have a `position` property. I have a second structure that needs to keep track of the objects for quick lookup of which objects are at which positions. I am currently using a grid (vector of vectors) to represent possible positions, each holding indexes into the vector of objects for the objects currently at the position. However, when an object is deleted from the vector (which happens very frequently, up to hundreds of times per iteration), my current resort is to loop through every grid position and decrement any indexes greater than the deleted index, which is slow and clumsy. Additional thoughts in regards to this problem in context are much appreciated, but my key question concerns the above examples.

Comment: Your two examples are UB because `erase(begin)` invalidates all iterators, pointers, and references. Can't you just store the _index_, not any iterator, and adjust as needed as you go along? I had a similar problem recently where I realised I was at risk of invaliding an iterator I was using - and then spent ages worrying about reallocation, etc - before realising that all I need is to know which index the element of interest is (or in your case, was) at in order to get back to it later. So whether the vector has been reallocated or not now doesn't matter at all, and my code just works.

Comment: @underscore_d also index can become invalid after `erase` (or stay valid but index to a different element)

Comment: @mvidelgauz Yes, I just edited to say that the OP can adjust the index if they know how it's 'drifting'. That is defined behaviour, rather than assuming they can adjust an iterator or pointer later, since the entire buffer might have been moved during the manipulation.

Comment: The second example is not UB.  The `shared_ptr` is just entirely independent of the `vector`.

Comment: The simplest solution will be to go for a `vector` of `shared_ptr`s, with your "observers" being `weak_ptr`s.

Comment: @aschepler OK, that's not UB, but is it really doing what the OP thinks it is? It's just copying the element and returning a pointer to the copy. Why not just take a copy by-value in that case? The OP wants some kind of ill-defined 'reference to a position in the container', not just a copy of any element, which is what both of these give them.

Comment: @underscore_d my feeling is that `vector` is not best way to implement such things (very volatile containers). May be `map`? Even using `int`s as keys, with map they will stay valid always except when that the same key is erased

Comment: @mvidelgauz Indeed, or `list`, which seems even better - only invalidates iterators for the `erase()`d element.

Comment: @mvidelgauz If the container type can be changed, a `std::list` would be the simplest thing giving the desired behavior.

Comment: @underscore_d and @aschepler you both are right. again I am caught with my disregarding of `list` existence, my bad...

Comment: @aschepler Yes, the container type can definitely be changed, in-fact, that is the crux of my question, to ask what alternate approaches (as mine is clearly not valid in its current state) would be best for the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to have the vector store `std::shared_ptr` objects, and issue `std::weak_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` objects to refer to the object in question.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> ints;
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    ints.emplace_back(std::make_shared<int>(int(i)));
}
std::weak_ptr<int> my_important_int = ints[6000];
{
    auto lock = my_important_int.lock();
    if(lock) std::cout << *lock << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "index 6000 expired." << std::endl;
}

auto erase_it = std:remove_if(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](auto & i) {return (*i) > 5000 && ((*i) % 4) != 0;});
ints.erase(erase_it, ints.end());

{
    auto lock = my_important_int.lock();
    if(lock) std::cout << *lock << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "index 6000 expired." << std::endl;
}

ints.erase(ints.begin(), ints.end());

{
    auto lock = my_important_int.lock();
    if(lock) std::cout << *lock << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "index 6000 expired." << std::endl;
}
```

Which should print out:

```
6000
6000
index 6000 expired.
```

Answer (score 2):

A container that stores key/value pairs might work for you. For example, `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

When using these containers, you'd keep a reference to the desired object by storing the key. If you want to modify said object, just look it up in the container using the key. Now you can add/remove other objects as much as you want without affecting the object in question (assuming the added/removed objects have unique keys).

Comment: `std::list` might be better, as using a `map` would mean adding a requirement for keys: if these have no meaning in the OP's case, they would have to be artificially/arbitrarily grafted onto the program's design. In contrast, with `list`, they could just keep safe iterators/pointers/references to elements, which would only be invalidated by `erase()`ing that specific element. Btw, they get the same guarantees with `map`s too, but again with the added requirement of keys that might not have any use.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a way for you to keep using a vector and change the way you manage your objects, then you won't get much more performance than what you have now.

Otherwise, you can use a *stable* vector ([here's the boost version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/container/stable_vector.html)). It is essentially a vector of pointers, which grants it iterator and reference stability. This means that iterators (pointers) and references to the elements are not invalidated by any operation other than removing the element itself.

Of course, there are some big drawbacks to this, mainly in performance. The two main performance issues are the fact that you go through a pointer every time you want to access an element, and the fact that the elements are not stored contiguously (which of course impacts the speed of iteration).

However, it also has advantages over other pointer-heavy data types (lists, sets, maps). Mainly, it performs lookup and pushbacks in constant time, even though it's slower than a normal vector.

Then again, if you really need performance, you might want to keep your vector and rethink your design around it.